# Delete .xlsx or .pdf after closing file

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, process

I'm trying to delete .xlsx or .pdf files after using them. When files are created I display them, but then users want automatic file deletion after closing them.

I've tried couple of things, but none of them seem to work properly. Issue:

When opened multiple files (.xlsx or .pdf) I can't terminate a single process, like just a single file. Instead what happens is that file get's deleted only when I close all same processes (Excel or PDF files). As I investigated this happens because Excel or PDF works as one instance only. However code works as expected when I have only one file opened...

This is what I have so far:

```
 var process= Process.Start(file_path); //file_path is global variable
 Set_event(process);

 private void Set_event(Process process)
 {
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Exited += new EventHandler(Delete_File);
 }

 public void Delete_File(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        //Delete file on close
        File.Delete(file_path);
 }
```

I've also tried with **DeleteOnClose** method of **FileOptions**, but unfortunally that doesn't display file to user and doesn't quite delete file immediately after using them, only after my win app is closed. That isn't my desired output, but at least files are deleted, so If I could fix that I would be partially satisfied too. Here is my line for that:

```
   var open_file = new FileStream(file_path,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.ReadWrite, 512, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
```

With all that said, are there any other options I missed ? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: The event is probably sent before the other process closes completely. Try adding a small delay

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, you mean in Delete_File method? I'm not sure that would help anything, but at least worth trying, thanks. Will let know about outcome...

Comment: You get an error because *something* keeps the file still open. That's either the application you started or something else. Most likely, it's the application you started. You can use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find which process locks a specific file.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, that is main issue, but I mentioned that allready. PDF or Excel uses one instance only, every file get's opened in that instance. And I need to close certain file while leave other intact. Upper code works when you close all PDF/Excel files.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I tried with monitoring directory with FileSystemWatcher too, but there is no filter for "FileClosed". However, I managed to opened it via FileSystemWatcher and notify if file is opened. Just can't figure out on how to delete file after closing.

Comment: FSW doesn't receive `File Closed` events - there are no such events to begin with. *How* does the application close? How does it close the file? Did it close it at all? Use `Process Explorer` to see whether the application is still running in the background. Use `Find > Find File Handle` as [shown here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows) to see which application instance is keeping the file open

Comment: `Process.Start("someFile.xlsx")` doesn't start an application. It tells the *Shell* to find the associated application and execute the `Open` shell verb with that path as argument. Depending on the application, the same instance could be used to open multiple files.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, application does not close. It's a .dll that creates .pdf or .xlsx files (OpenXML), and after It's created that same .dll opens file with Process.Start. All the logic is however inside .dll. Maybe I should call "Process.Start" with Exited_event inside my app instead in .dll ?... I will try Process Explorer too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for your help, but I've solved issue in a little different way as I started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried almost everything I could find (different variations of Exited_Event for Process, monitoring with FileSystemWatcher, creating files with DeleteOnClose - even API), but none of them worked as expected.

Everything ends or fails with issue I described in first place - some apps, like Microsoft Excel or Adobe Acrobat uses one instance to open a file (.pdf or .xls/.xlsx), so you can't just reference a single file as object while you have opened more files. That means you either end up with an error when trying to assign Exited_event to single file, or no error but file gets deleted only when you close all files with same type...

**BUT fortunate enough** I figured out one thing: **WHEN** you have opened more than one file in question (.pdf or .xlsx) something happens in background of OS: If you loop through processes of same type at that time, you'll get a list of particular instance that is in use.

In other words, while you have 2 Excel files opened, loop through processes is showing you only a file which is currently active for "EXCEL" process.

So, that leaded me to a completely new approach that might solve this issue. In order to have a complete solution for this you have to:

**1.** Create a method to check whether file is no longer in use.

**2.** Set a Timer with a delay of 2 seconds, to make sure process really ends. Maybe this should be incremented for different purposes...

**3.** Set a Timer_tick event, where you loop processes to see whether particular file is listed as active, and If user has already closed this file.  As described by other users this method isn't quite accurate, but with setting delay for Timer I think there shouldn't be any problems anymore.

Here is a complete code for this (for .pdf and .xlsx - that is what I needed):

```
   //as global variable
   System.Windows.Forms.Timer delete_file = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); 

    Process.Start(file_path); //file_path is global variable

    delete_file.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); 
    delete_file.Interval = (2000);              
    delete_file.Enabled = true;                     
    delete_file.Start();

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean file_is_opened = false;

        // Loop processes and list active files in use
        foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
          if (process.MainWindowTitle.Contains(Path.GetFileName(file_path)))
          {
             file_is_opened = true;
          }
        }

         //If our file is not listed under active processes we check 
         //whether user has already closed file - If so, we finally delete It
         if (file_is_opened==false)
         {
            if (!File_In_Use(new FileInfo(file_path)))
            {
                 File.Delete(file_path);
                 delete_file.Enabled = false;
                 delete_file.Stop();
                 return;
             }
          }
     }

     private bool File_In_Use(FileInfo file)
     {
         //Method to check whether file is in use

         FileStream stream = null;

         try
         {
              //If file doesn't exist
              if (!file.Exists)
              {
                     return false;
              }

              stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
         }
         catch (IOException)
         {
               //File is unavailable:
              //because someone writes to It, or It's being processed
              return true;
         }
         finally
         {
            if (stream!=null)
            {
              stream.Close();
            }
         }

             //File not locked
             return false;
      }
```

This is how I did It. It might not be a perfect solution, but that works for me on Win 10 with no errors so far.

If someone has a suggestion to fix upper code, please let me know. Otherwise I hope this will help someone in future as I noticed there were already some questions about this in past, with no proper answer.

Comment: That's not a weird thing or something that happens in the background. The same application instance is used to handle all documents. Unless *that other* application properly closes the file, eg through a VBA macro, it's still open. That's how Windows, the shell and COM applications work since the 1990s.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,well now It works for me, that's most important :)

Comment: When you call `Process.Start(somePath)` the *Windows Shell* tries to find the application registered to open that file. Some applications are configured to open a separate instance per file. Clearly, that's *very* wasteful. Other applications are configured to use a single instance to handle multiple files. The Shell uses COM settings in the registry and COM interfaces in the applications to start them and tell them to open files.

Comment: It doesn't work reliably *yet*. What happens if the user works on some other spreadsheet at the same time? The application will freeze.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, I see that when facing my problem. However, whatever I searched online I couldn't find anywhere something simple as my solution is. I just hope that everything will work fine on other PC's too.

Comment: On the other hand, if the user uses *another* application like Libre Calc or some other PDF reader (like the *browser*), that loop will fail again because it won't detect that the files are still open.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I use this only for export of my DB data to .pdf and .xlsx. Meanwhile I allready tested if the user works on some other spreadsheet at the same time - It works, either on file I need to delete either on different files.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, as for different apps, like  Libre Calc or some other PDF reader ...Well that is something others will have to test, but maybe this example will work too.